# C# is it possible to store like classes into a collection?

Tags: c#, collections

Tried to title my post as best I could, but here goes.

I have 5 classes for various "effect" animation stuff that can be done to an animation (alpha change, color change, position change, rotation change, scale change). They are all the same aside from variable types. They all use an abstract class for methods that could be shared between them all along with methods that are override in the derived classes.

I have a class that is for handling all the animations of a game object called AnimationHandler. What it does is store all the effect animations (along with the sprite animations) for my game's objects and handling them.

What I want to do is store all the effects into one dictionary that is then used to handle all changes to an animation for that object. I was wondering if it was possible to do or if it would be just easier to have 5 separate dictionaries to handle each effect separately?

The issue that I'm trying to figure out is how to access the variables that aren't in the abstract class.

Here is the sample code for my base class and a derived class:

```
abstract class EffectAnimation
{
    protected EffectInfo Info;
    public EffectInfo info
    {
        get
        { return Info; }
    }

    protected EffectType TypeOfEffect;
    public EffectType typeofeffect
    {
        get
        { return TypeOfEffect; }
    }

    public abstract void NewAnimation();
    public void Update(double time) 
    { 
        AnimationDone(time);
        if (!info.Done)
        {
            if (UtilityAnimation.ReadyForNextFrame(time, Info.FrameLength))
            {
                Info.NextFrameTime = time + Info.FrameLength;
                ChangeValue();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Start(double time) 
    {
        Info.StartTime = time;
        Info.NextFrameTime = time + Info.FrameLength;
    }

    public abstract void ChangeValue();
    public abstract void Clamp();
    protected abstract void AnimationDone(double time);
}



class AlphaAnimation : EffectAnimation
{
    private float Change;
    public float change
    {
        get
        { return Change; }
        set
        { Change = value; }
    }

    private float End;
    public float end
    {
        get
        { return End; }
        set
        { End = value; }
    }

    private float Total;
    public float total
    {
        get
        { return Total; }
        set
        { Total = value; }
    }

    public void NewAnimation(EffectInfo stuff, float starting, float ending, float partialtotal)
    {
        Total = starting + partialtotal;
        Info = stuff;
        End = ending;
        Info.Initialize();
        Change = UtilityAnimation.MakeFadeAmount(stuff.AnimationLength, starting, ending, stuff.FPS);
    }

    public void ChangeValue()
    { Total += Change; }

    private void Clamp()
    {
        if (Change > 0) // animation is positive
        {
            if (Total > End)
            {
                Total = End;
            }
        }
        else // animation is negative
        {
            if (Total < End)
            {
                Total = End;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AnimationDone(double time)
    {
        Clamp();
        if ((Total == End) && (time >= Info.DoneTime()))
        { Info.Done = true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what do you want to know? And it would be better if you name private fields with lowercase letters and public properties with uppercase letters, like:
protected EffectType typeOfEffect;
public EffectType TypeOfEffect
{
   ....
}
Refer: http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can simply store the abstract type "EffectAnimation". So make a List / Dictionary of that type.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make it so I can use the abstract type "EffectAnimation" in a dictionary that can handle all 5 of the derived effects needs so I don't have to have 5 separate dictionaries that I have to handle.

Comment: The issue that I'm running into is that I want to be able to get the values from the derived class but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: What kind of values from derived classes do you need in this case? I think you should abstract all 'general' the properties of animation you need into EffectAnimation class.

Comment: The only variable that I need at the time would be the Total. I went back and checked after typing up each and determined that I wont' need to access the change or end variables just the total.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for (accessing for instance `change` of `AlphaAnimation` via a reference of type `EffectAnimation`) is impossible without reflection or checking for the actual type. That being said, if possible, the design should be changed such that the desired effect of the animation can be triggered without knowing its type. This can be difficult depending on the case; in some cases it might make no sense altogether.

Comment: Can I use the dynamic keyword to create dynamic variables in the base class?

Comment: Ok so what you are meaning then is have something like so:

Comment: `code`    public abstract dynamic ReturnTotal(); // in AlphaAnimation         public override dynamic ReturnTotal()
        { return Total; }

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken (I have deleted my comment); thanks for the clarification. However, I don't see how this would help here.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, shouldn't I be able to use the base class to call my derived class's functions?

Comment: Yes, this is the case for virtual member functions which are overridden in the derived classes. The base class is not aware of other functions in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution;

```
List<EffectAnimation> animations = new List<EffectAnimation>();
animations.Add(new AlphaAnimation());

EffectAnimation item = animations[0];
if(item is AlphaAnimation)
{
    AlphaAnimation alphaItem = item as AlphaAnimation;
    float total = alphaItem.Total;
    float change = alphaItem.Change;
}
```

This is basically just casting it to the right class and then you can easily access the properties you need. You can still add all your animations to the same list - just make sure to check if it is the right one when you take one out.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try if my idea to add an abstract dynamic return function to the base class and override it in the derived class doesn't work. Still new to C# programming as I mainly learned C++ in college.